# unable to login into recently created administrative user account

Tags: login, gui, adduser

the account is active, and I can log in using a TTY but mot through the GUI. when logged it shows the same image active with the other user account but a message saying:

```
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
```

running

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

get

```
E: could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: resource temporarily unavailable)  
E: unable to lock the administrative directory (/var/lib/dpkg), is another process using it?
```

Comment: How exactly did you create the new account? it sounds like you didn't create/assign a home directory for it. The `apt-get update` error is probably an unrelated issue.

Comment: yes that was the problem. its OK now

Answer (score 0):

> No directory, logging in with HOME=/

This shows you haven't create a home for the newly created user.
I suppose you use `useradd` command without `-d` option:

`man useradd`

```
   -d, --home HOME_DIR
       The new user will be created using HOME_DIR as the value for the
       user's login directory. The default is to append the LOGIN name to
       BASE_DIR and use that as the login directory name. The directory
       HOME_DIR does not have to exist but will not be created if it is
       missing.
```

The directory will not be created if it is missing.

So it's better to not use `useradd`, use `adduser` instead.

> E: could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: resource
>   temporarily unavailable) E: unable to lock the administrative
>   directory (/var/lib/dpkg), is another process using it?

Now this error means that there is another process using `dpkd`. So to solve this

- either wait to end that process(mainly this raise when you open
  software center and trying to install from terminal),
- Kill the old process by searching for it using `ps aux | grep dpkg` then `kill -9 PID`
- or you can remove the lock file

  ```
  sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
  sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
  ```